# Why my raspberry pi 3 model b is going crazy

Tags: pi-3

My raspberry pi 3 model b is doing things automatically like opening browser and inspect elements ,taking screenshots without my control.my os is noobs.Before noobs , i tried ubuntu mate 18.04.02, same problem persisted so i formatted the sd card and again installed noobs but the problem still exist. Please somebody help me to resolve this.

Comment: Where are you downloading the noobs installer from? Maybe it's a bad/corrupt source, or an unstable build. I was thinking this might be a keyboard issue if you're using one that is. Can you be more specific about your system setup?

Comment: Thanks for replying me.I installed noobs from raspberry pi .org  website and  when i connected the pi to the LAN its going crazy .i think keyboard is working fine ..because its a wired usb key board and i tested with my laptop .its working fine then.when i connct the raspberry pi to wifi it works fine again.

Comment: Weird, I have no idea what the cause could be, I just hope it isn't a Hardware issue

Comment: Is your internet connection protected? Have any computers on your network been hacked? Download ‘Raspbian Stretch with Desktop’, flash to sd card with Etcher, make sure you change the default password during installation.

Comment: Dont know whether the computers been hacked or not but i will try your steps and i will let you know,thanks bro.